# Android: ¿Cambiar imagen de lista segun respuesta de Json?

Tags: android, json, listview, android-imageview

Buenas a todos. Cargo un `ListView` desde `JSON` para hacer reservas.

Todas las reservas libres de la lista tienen una imagen de un icono color verde (que indica que están disponibles), ahora las que están ocupadas deberían aparecer con un ícono rojo.

JSON:

```
{ 'reservas': [{ 'idr':'1116630406', 'idusuario': '', 'fecha': '2017-08-28 13:00' }
```

¿Cómo sé qué reservas están ocupadas?

Cuando 'idusuario' no está vacío.

Estoy hace un par de días intentando de cambiar imagen para indicar si una reserva está ocupada o no. Lo que estaba tratando de hacer era lo siguiente:

```
if (!idusuario.equals("")){
likeIconGreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_like_red);
}
```

El problema es que la variable que contiene al 'usuario' del JSON se encuentra dentro de un `AsyncTask` entonces no me permite utilizar `setImageResource`. No sé cómo lo podría realizar. Desde ya, gracias.

#### ReservasLibres.java

```
public class ReservasLibres extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private String TAG = ReservasLibres.class.getSimpleName();
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ListView lv;

private Toolbar reservasLibresToolbar;

private TextView tvHorario;

ImageView likeIconGreen;


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listaReservasLibres;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista_reservas_libres);

    //Toolbar
    reservasLibresToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.reservasLibresToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(reservasLibresToolbar);


    String nombreLocal = getIntent().getStringExtra("nombre");
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Reservas Disponibles");
    getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(nombreLocal);

    String horario = getIntent().getStringExtra("horario");
    tvHorario = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHorario);

    tvHorario.setText(horario);

    listaReservasLibres = new ArrayList<>();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewReservasLibres);

    likeIconGreen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.likeIconGreen);

    new GetReservasLibres().execute();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

    //ALERTDIALOG "¿Confirma reserva?".

    class hacerReserva extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String idusuario = getIntent().getExtras().getString("idusuario");
        String idc = getIntent().getExtras().getString("idc");
        String idt = listaReservasLibres.get(position).get("idt");


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String hacerReservaURL = "http://xxx";

            try {
                URL url = new URL(hacerReservaURL);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("dni","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(dni,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);

                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";


                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return result;


            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ReservasLibres.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Por favor, espere...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            if (result.contains("1") || result.contains("TRUE")){

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReservasLibres.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_hacer_reserva_exitoso)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_aceptar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                Intent intent = new Intent(ReservasLibres.this, ReservasPendientes.class);
                                intent.putExtra("idusuario", idusuario);
                                finish();
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

            }
            else if (result.contains("0") || result.contains("FALSE")){

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReservasLibres.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_hacer_reserva_fallido)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_aceptar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                finish();
                                startActivity(getIntent());
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }

        }
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReservasLibres.this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_hacer_reserva)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_aceptar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //Aceptar
                    new hacerReserva().execute();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancelar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //Cancelar
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

private class GetReservasLibres extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String idusuario = getIntent().getStringExtra("idusuario");
    String idm = getIntent().getStringExtra("idm");


    private String url = "http://xxx";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ReservasLibres.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Por favor, espere...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONArray reservasLibres = jsonObj.getJSONArray("reservas");

                for (int i = 0; i < reservasLibres.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject tl = reservasLibres.getJSONObject(i);

                    String idt = tl.getString("idt");
                    String idusuario = tl.getString("idusuario");
                    String fecha = tl.getString("fecha");

                    //Formateo fecha
                    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
                    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
                    Date myDate = inputFormat.parse(fecha);
                    String outputDateStr = outputFormat.format(myDate);

                    HashMap<String, String> reservaLibre = new HashMap<>();

                    reservaLibre.put("idt", idt);
                    reservaLibre.put("idusuario", idusuario);
                    reservaLibre.put("fecha", outputDateStr);

                    listaReservasLibres.add(reservaLibre);

                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                ReservasLibres.this, listaReservasLibres,
                R.layout.list_item_reservas_libres,
                new String[]{"fecha"}, new int[]{R.id.tvFechaReservaLibre});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: seria bueno que editaras tu pregunta y añadieras el código completo de tu clase para así entender mejor como funciona tu ListView.

Comment: Gracias @David ya lo edité.

Answer (score 2):

Mi sugerencia es la siguiente:

1.-Crear un objeto 'Reserva' con los atributos de tu json.

2.-Crear una clase que extienda de 'ArrayAdater', esta clase te pedirá en su constructor una Actividad y un ArrayList de reservas. Aqui es donde esta la magia, tienes que hacer un override al método "getView", de este mismo adapter y inflas tu view, ejemplo:

```
 @Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup){
    final Reserva reserva = getItem(i);
    if (view == null){
        view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.reserva_fila,null);
        ImageView img = view.findById(R.id.img);
        if(reseva.hasId){
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_like_red);
        }else{
            //imagen verde
        }

    }
    return view;
}
```

3.-En la clase donde tienes tu lista, instancias tu adaptador y se lo pones a tu lista:

```
 reservasAdapter = new ReservasAdapter(this, arrayListReservas);
 listView.setAdapter(platesAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, hay cosas que doy por hechas, como por ejemplo que al ImageView `likeIconGreen` le tienes colocado por defecto (en el codigo xml) la imagen de color verde, entre otras cosas.

Ahora bien para cambiar la imagen del ImageView likeIconGreen desde la tarea asicronica (AsyncTask) `GetReservasLibres`, tienes que realizar el cambio en el metodo `onPostExecute()`, ya que es el metodo que se comunica con la interfaz de usuario. Ahora bien tu dijiste "que no podias utilizar el metodo `setImageResource()` dentro del AsyncTask" eso es porque "lo mas seguro" tratabas de utilizar ese metodo dentro del `doInBackground()` (es algo que tambien doy por hecho) que es el metodo que se ejecuta en segundo plano y que no se comunica con la interfaz de usuario. En un AsyncTask todos los cambios que bayas a realizar a la interfaz grafica, debes de hacerlo en el metodo `onPostExecute()` que es el metodo que comunica con la interfaz grafica (o de usuario) y se ejecuta en primer plano.

Bien, con esos puntos claros, paso a explicar una forma de solucionar tu problema.

### Solucion

En tu clase AsyncTask debes de agregar el metodo `onPostExecute()` y este debe recibir como parametro el `idUsuario` que se retornara desde el `doInBackground()`. Para eso tiene que modificar tu AsyncTask, de los tres tipo de objetos que recibe `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` el ultimo tienes que cambiarlo de Void a String:  `AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>`. Al metodo `protected void doInBackground(Void... arg0)` tienes que cambiarle su tipo de retorno de void a String `protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0)` para que puedas retornar el valor de la variable idUsuario. Y por ultimo agregas el metodo `onPostExecute()`.

Para retornar el valor de la variable idUsuario tienes que declararla como variable del metodo, fuera del for y fuera del if, luego dentro del for le asignas su valor como lo estabas haciendo y por ultimo la retornas.

En el metodo  onPostExecute() recibes el valor de la variable y lo utilizas dentro de if para saber si esta vacia o no, de acuerdo a eso cambias la imagen del ImageView likeIconGreen, tal como muestras en el if de la pregunta.

```
private class GetReservasLibres extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String idusuario = getIntent().getStringExtra("idusuario");
    String idm = getIntent().getStringExtra("idm");


    private String url = "http://xxx";      

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ReservasLibres.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Por favor, espere...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        // Se declara la variable que se retornara
        String idusuario = "";

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONArray reservasLibres = jsonObj.getJSONArray("reservas");

                for (int i = 0; i < reservasLibres.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject tl = reservasLibres.getJSONObject(i);

                    String idt = tl.getString("idt");
                    idusuario = tl.getString("idusuario"); // Se le asigna el valor a la variable
                    String fecha = tl.getString("fecha");

                    //Formateo fecha
                    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
                    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
                    Date myDate = inputFormat.parse(fecha);
                    String outputDateStr = outputFormat.format(myDate);

                    HashMap<String, String> reservaLibre = new HashMap<>();

                    reservaLibre.put("idt", idt);
                    reservaLibre.put("idusuario", idusuario);
                    reservaLibre.put("fecha", outputDateStr);

                    listaReservasLibres.add(reservaLibre);

                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return idusuario;
    }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String idusuario) {
         super.onPostExecute(result);

         if (!idusuario.equals("")) {
             ReservasLibres.this.likeIconGreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_like_red);
         }

     }

}
```

Comment: las cosas que diste por hechas son acertadas. Ahora bien, intenté pasarle la variable String 'idusuario' al onPostExecute, pero no sabía que debía modificar AsyncTask y doInBackground. Lo voy a probar y te aviso. Muchas gracias por responder.

Comment: Me da este error en el if:
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at com.sho.lui.webturno.TurnosLibres$GetTurnosLibres.onPostExecute

Comment: Yo declaré el imageview likeIconGreen en la clase

Comment: prueba colocando `ReservasLibres.this.likeIconGreen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_like_red);`

Comment: No hay caso u.u

Comment: La verdad no se me ocurre porque el error, yo lo veo todo bien. Trata reconstruyendo tu proyecto, para saber si es un error de Android Studio. Para reconstruirlo ve a la pestaña **Build>Rebuild Project**. Despues de reconstruirlo vuelve a ejecutarlo. 

Me dejas saber.

Comment: Qué tal David?. Traté reconstruirlo y también limpiarlo, pero sigo teniendo el mismo resultado. Es muy raro. Tendrá que ver que las imágenes están en el layout list_item_reservaslibres.xml en vez de lista_reservaslibres.xml? cuando intente esto te hago saber.

Comment: @luis_snk Si tienes tu proyecto en GitHub, puedes compartirme el enlace para probar tu código y saber por que seria el error.